# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.17.10 Laravel

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-valet

I'm getting a `502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.17.10` error when trying to visit a Laravel `.test` site with Valet. I'm having no issues with another Laravel app running on `.test`. I have tried reinstalling nginx, php, valet, and have tried using php versions 7.2 ,7.3 & 7.4 for valet. Any ideas?

Comment: i have same problem after ubuntu upgrade to 20.04. Are you solved this issue?

Comment: I can't remember exactly but I think I ended up reinstalling php and valet at a minimum. I'm on a Mac so I did the installs via homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still experiencing this issue:

1. Open your `Homestead.yaml` file
2. Add the following lines to the `sites` option:

   php: YOUR_PHP_VERSION

   type: apache
3. Run the command `vagrant reload --provision`